# How to set a prototype for a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, oop, json, casting

I am receiving some JSON object from the server, and I want to 'typecast' or 'bless' it to an object with already defined methods. Is there any way to set a prototype for a plain JSON object?

```
function MyClass(someValue) {
    this.myProperty = someValue;
}

MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function() { return "Here's " + this.myProperty + "!"};

var json = {myProperty : 'someValue'};

// ??? json.prototype = MyClass doesn't work, of course.

var result = json.someMethod();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Here is the answer (which is IE-incompatible):

```
json.__proto__ = MyClass.prototype;
```

Thankfully, I don't need no %$@$%# IE in my application.

(When I do, there is another possibility: create a wrapper function in MyClass prototype which copies all properties from JSON to the new object; shallow-copying should be enough).

Comment: I don't know that that will work in Safari or Chrome. What you describe as the "other possibility" is in fact the best way to do it.

Comment: @Pointy I have tested it, it does. For IE, I have found a cool hack which can be used in lieu of __proto__: http://www.webmasters.am/blog/tag/__proto__/ .

Comment: OK, well, it's not standardized (even with ECMAScript 5) so use at your own risk :-)

Comment: @pointy - lolz. first there was the 'good parts' and now there are the 'bad parts'. i know who wrote the first one, looks like someone else is trying to write the second.

Comment: How disappointing to find the perfect question matching my own current problem, but with a non-applicable answer for my needs. Copying properties doesn't seem quite so glamorous as a magic bullet would have been!

Comment: Is this way is hacky or it is a proper way?

json.__proto__ = MyClass.prototype;

Answer (score 4):

Well, I can suggest to try out these:

- By adding the needed functions to ALL Javascript objects (bad practice)

  ```
  Object.prototype.lol = function() { alert(this.a); };
  var x = {a : 'b'};
  x.lol();
  ```
- By "extending" JSON with a function:

  ```
  var json = {a : 'b', b : 123};
  function extend(obj) {
      obj.func1 = function(param) {
          alert(this[param]);
      }
  }
  extend(json);
  json.func1('b');
  ```
- By "making" the object into a function:

  ```
  var json = {a : 'b', b : 123};
  function extendToFunc(obj) {
      var theLibrary = function(obj) {
          /**
           * The same as above.
          */
          this.func1 = function(param) {
               alert(obj[param]);
          }
      };
      return new theLibrary(obj);
  }
  var jsonFunc = extendToFunc(json);
  jsonFunc.func1('b');
  ```

Or you can use a JS framework for that. Or any other method that you can think of :) My examples are easy, they can be extended into anything sophisticated you need.

Comment: Adding these functions manually one by one violates the most important programmer's virtue: laziness.

Comment: You don't have to add them manually. You can build a small framework just for that. It would add all the necessary methods you could wish - you just have to pass all JSON through that framework. I don't see much difference in adding the functions to one "extending" method/function rather than applying with .prototype. And I think my approach is better for analyzing the flow of the application, debugging.