# Proper way of assigning to __proto__ property

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

I have some objects deserialized from JSON to which I'd like to assign a new prototype in order to provide various getter and setter functions. The obvious way to do this (as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097007/how-to-set-a-prototype-for-a-json-object)) is to set

```
myJsonObj.__proto__ = { function1: /* ... */, function2: /* ... */ };
```

However, as MDC [helpfully points out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), the `__proto__` property is non-standard and deprecated. Is there any standards-compliant way (for some definition of "standards") to achieve the same effect, without having to create lots of new wrapper objects?

Comment: The documentation you linked to suggests that you "Use Object.getPrototypeOf() instead"  ( [getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) ).  So something like this:  `var proto = myJsonObj.getPrototypeOf(); proto.function1 = /*whatever*/; proto.function2=/*whatever*/;`

Comment: Lee, if I'm not mistaken, calling `Object.getPrototypeOf(myJsonObj)` would give me `Object.prototype` (since `myJsonObj` didn't have any other constructor). That means that by following your suggestion, I would be modifying `Object` (very bad) instead of injecting a class into `myJsonObj`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standards compliant way to change the prototype of an object after its creation.
There is a standards compliant way to create objects with whatever prototype you desire while parsing from JSON.

From http://www.json.org/js.html:

> The optional reviver parameter is a
>   function that will be called for every
>   key and value at every level of the
>   final result. Each value will be
>   replaced by the result of the reviver
>   function. This can be used to reform
>   generic objects into instances of
>   pseudoclasses, or to transform date
>   strings into Date objects.