# Replicating python's __call__ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I want to replicate instantiating a callable class **without** using the module pattern.

The following is my best attempt at this. However, it uses `__proto__` which I'm not sure about. Can this be done without `__proto__`?

```
function classcallable(cls) {
    /*
     * Replicate the __call__ magic method of python and let class instances
     * be callable.
     */
    var new_cls = function () {
        var obj = Object.create(cls.prototype);
        // create callable
        // we use func.__call__ because call might be defined in
        // init which hasn't been called yet.
        var func = function () {
            return func.__call__.apply(func, arguments);
        };
        func.__proto__ = obj;
        // apply init late so it is bound to func and not cls
        cls.apply(func, arguments);
        return func;
    }
    new_cls.prototype = cls.prototype;
    return new_cls

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with taking advantage of prototype inheritance? It's just another scheme for polymorphism.

Comment: I'm not against prototypical inheritance, in fact that is what I use. I was talking about `__proto__` specifically since it's not cross-browser or standard.

Comment: It is cross-browser, actually (though IE and [older versions of?] Opera don't seem to support it), [and is in the ECMAScript ed6 spec. draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-B.3.1), so at some point it will be standard (unless they remove it from the specification in the future). You're right that it isn't standard at the moment, though.

Comment: How can something be both cross-browser and **not** work in IE?

Comment: What's your motivation for avoiding the module pattern? Seeing how obviously Javascript doesn't really have callable objects and seems to go on about this aspect of language design in the opposite way compared to Python

Comment: Note that `.__proto__` is the same as `.constructor.prototype`

Comment: @millimoose It does, though. JavaScript functions are objects just like any other JavaScript object, being created from the constructor/factory function `Function()`, they just happen to have the feature of being callable. `(function() {}).constructor -> function Function() {[native code]}`, `(function() {}).__proto__ -> function () {}`. The native code implementation may differ between platforms, but from the point of view of the language abstraction, functions are nothing more than special-cased objects.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Only when getting `.__proto__`, not when setting it. Setting the constructor's prototype after the fact has no effect on the already-created object, to change the prototype used by created objects you have to set those directly. And while you could probably remove all the properties in `.constructor.prototype` and then add new ones, that would mean the change in prototype properties would affect all objects created by that constructor, not just the given function (which can be desirable, of course, but may not be in this situation).

Comment: @JAB I should've said "a way to hook into calling objects" I guess. Another way to look at what you describe is that Javascript has first-class functions, which isn't necessarily the same language abstraction as callable objects. (Consider Haskell which has the same dichotomy.) I admit I'm struggling how to phrase this, but it's like putting the same building blocks required to make the language in the opposite order. Python starts with a consistent low-level and builds high-level abstractions on it. Javascript starts at the high level but makes its language features appear "objecty".

Comment: @millimoose True enough, though due to the status of functions as objects it's probably better to stick with closures for "callable object" functionality in JavaScript. (Which apparently is pretty much what the module pattern does as far as I can tell, and thus the name seem kind of silly to me because heavy usage of anonymous functions and closures is not so much a design pattern as it is a paradigm of functional programming.)

Comment: @millimoose (Though, technically, Python also has full capability for closures, they're just not quite as nice-looking as in other languages due to Python's anonymous function expression, `lambda`, allowing only single statements; named inner functions still work just as well as anonymous ones, and Python does give you the ability to dynamically bind functions to object contexts, although not as flexibly as in JavaScript.) ...And I'm rambling, time to go home.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Like JAB said, I'm setting `__proto__` so they aren't equivalent.

Comment: @millimoose I started off with the module pattern, essentially copying `d3` idioms. The reason I moved off of it was that I did not want private variables/methods and needed `this` to be consistently used. With those constraints; the module pattern's only real benefit is that it returns a function.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Why even have the term cross-browser if it doesn't include IE? Does anyone consider code that works in webkit, chrome, and firefox to be noteworthy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410176/proper-way-of-assigning-to-proto-property - has the answer for a similar question.

Comment: @RijviRajib How so? Other than they both mention `__proto__`? This is wrapping a class before any instances are instantiated.

Comment: no, using "new " and wanting inheritance means you'll have to tack-on props in a loop or return an objectObject, not a function.

Comment: Since `__proto__` is non-standard, currently there is no standard way to give a function a prototype other than `Function`. Future  versions of JavaScript might allow you to do something like `cls.prototype <| function () { return __call__.apply(this, arguments); }`. Details here: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proto_operator&s=prototype+operator

Comment: Another upcoming feature that could solve this would be the apply hook on proxies: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies

Comment: I'm already taking advantages of the JavaScript Proxies (the latest Firefox supports it), IMHO its one of the most powerful meta-programming tool in JavaScript yet. And if I understand the question correctly, then it definitely can solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

### Proxy

If you are against using `__proto__` or anything related to it but still want the inheritability, you could make use of [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```
var ObjectCallable_handler = {
    get: function get(self, key) {
        if (self.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return self[key];
        } else { return self.__inherit__[key]; }
    },
    apply: function apply(self, thisValue, args) {
        return (self.__call__ || self.__inherit__.__call__).apply(self, args);
    }
};

function ObjectCallable(cls) {
    var p = new Proxy(function() { }, ObjectCallable_handler);
    p.__inherit__ = cls;
    return p;
}
```

#### Pros

- Maintains inheritability.
- Does not involve a traditional prototype chain.
- [ES6 draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies).

#### Cons

- [Currently supported](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Proxies) only by Firefox >=24.

---

### setPrototypeOf

If the lack of support for Proxies dismays you, you could try a [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) polyfill instead.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || function (obj, proto) {
    obj.__proto__ = proto;
    return obj;
}

function ObjectCallable(cls) {
    var f = function() { return f.__call__.apply(f, arguments); };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, cls);
    return f;
}
```

#### Pros

- Likely to work the best right now and in the future.
- [ES6 draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts).

#### Cons

- Makes use of the non-standard `__proto__` through the polyfill and *will* require testing across the engines/browsers you want to support.
- `setPrototypeOf` is [not currently implemented](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Object.setPrototypeOf) in any browser.

---

### copy

This is the simplest solution with the least amount of functionality, but it's guaranteed to work almost anywhere. Create a new function and clone an object's properties onto it.

```
function ObjectCallable(cls) {
    var f = function() { return f.__call__.apply(f, arguments); }, k;
    for (k in cls) {
        f[k] = cls[k];
    }
    return f;
}
```

#### Pros

- Works virtually everywhere.

#### Cons

- Does not maintain any semblance of an inheritance or prototype structure whatsoever.

---

### Conclusion

What you want to do with replicating Python's `__call__` functionality in JavaScript will require either more time as ES6 develops and becomes implemented in more engines or relying on non-standard functionality such as `__proto__`.