# Assign __proto__ to an interface to turn it into an object - clever or dangerous?

Tags: javascript, prototype, web-worker

When using postMessage() to copy data to/from a web worker, you can post an object that's a class. But on the far side, the received object is just the data (ie an interface, not a class).

[One person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410176/proper-way-of-assigning-to-proto-property) suggested assign the correct `__proto__` to that object on the receive side to turn it back into a class. This works. But is this solid & safe or is it asking for trouble?

I am not asking for opinion here (a big no-no), I'm asking are there specific technical issues that might bite me in the posterior.

Comment: Isn't `__proto__` browser specific?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may not support patching `__proto__` or, in the future, may stop supporting it.

I discovered this the hard way when my code stopped working when used in [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRT) HTML applications.

The properper way (in ES5) would be to call `Object.create(Constructor.prototype, obj)` ([see her for more examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create))

Comment: Ecmascript6 will have `Object.setPrototypeOf`

Comment: Is Object.create() any faster than my having a constructor that accepts the interface and assigns all properties?

Comment: @DavidThielen don't use proto for write properties. Use it only for readonly prop/member functions. PS for speed, it's faster to create....but slower to read from later....but it saves memory as the instances share the proto